# Wrapper in wrapper to position 5 div centered

Tags: html, css

I want to create a soundboard where i have 5 button in a row. If the screen become smaller it switch to the next row but all the buttons are centered in the middel.

here is the code. I've created a button wrapper with H:100% and W:100% and center the div in the middle of the other wrapper but that doenst work.

```css
.wrapper{
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1200px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:red;
 margin: auto;
}

.buttonwrapper{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:red;
}

.button{
 width: 150px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:black;
 margin: 10px 10px;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttonwrapper">
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;` and `display: inline-block;` like this.

```css
.wrapper{
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1200px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:red;
 margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.buttonwrapper{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button{
 width: 150px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:black;
 margin: 10px 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttonwrapper">
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
   <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```